# PCIE Data Link Layer error

Tags: graphic-drivers

I am looking for a Linux distro to install on a new home desktop. Long story short I decided to try with Elementary OS.

However I am not able to install it.

After booting up from the USB drive the first thing I see is that there is a problem in PCIe Data Link Layer(As far as I see that is connected to almost all Linux distros.) I cannot even try the system or install it... After 5 to 10 seconds it freezes and I need to restart...

I have NVIDIA GTX 760 OC 4GB which seems to be the problem. If I am to install my really old GPU a can install an run it but as soon as I run the GTX card it crashes... Before posting here I tried couple of fixes from the internet regarding the grub such as pci = aspm off but none of them worked.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated
Thanks